# setSinkId does not exist on HTMLMediaElement

Tags: javascript, html, webrtc

I'm creating a WebRTC application using Angular and I'm trying to control audio out using the setSinkId() method found on the HTMLMediaElement. Upon trying to call this method I am told it is not a function.

I've tried reading the WebRTC samples found here: https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/devices/input-output and I've read the documentation from the mozilla dev pages. They all say this method exists yet I cannot find it. I've inspected my lib.dom.d.ts file and the HTMLMediaElement has the sinkId property but this method is nowhere to be found.

```
function myFunc()
{
    let audio = HTMLMediaElement;
    audio.setSinkId("mydeviceID");
}
```

Expecting the method to exists on this element to change audio output source

Edit: I am using chrome v77

Comment: `setSinkId()` is listed as *"experimental"* per [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/setSinkId#Browser_compatibility). In Firefox, for example, it has to be manually enabled by the user, otherwise it isn't available at all. Perhaps however your code is being transpiled, doesn't include `setSinkId()`.

Comment: @TylerRoper I am using chrome v77. I am confused as it doesn't even show up as a method in the typescript definition file where the HTMLMediaElement is found.

Comment: I'm not familiar with TypeScript but wouldn't that indicate that it's not supported yet?

Comment: @TylerRoper I'm not sure. I'm not overly familiar with it myself. I'm trying to use it for one of my university class prohects. My script files for the project are in the javascript format. It's part of the HTML web API so I believe I should be able to access it. I'm using HTML5.

Comment: You're invoking it wrong. It's not a static method. Create an actual element first.

Comment: Have a look here https://webrtchacks.com/guide-to-safari-webrtc/

Answer (score 0):

You can crate own inteface extends HTMLVideoElement, like this:

```js
export interface LBVideoElement extends HTMLVideoElement {
    setSinkId(id: string);
}
```

Then import LBVideoElement and use this as type. Ex. angular

```js
_videoElement: ElementRef<LBVideoElement>;
this._videoElement.nativeElement.setSinkId(xxxx);
```

Answer (score 0):

As @typer-roper said in the comment:

> setSinkId() is listed as "experimental" per MDN.

The file `lib.dom.ts` provided by `typescript@5.0.4` does not provide a definition for 
`[instance HTMLMediaElement].setSinkId`.

If you want to call it  without using `as any` by force, you can write your own definition at your own risk:

> TypeScript is just JavaScript in runtime, and thus mandatory type definitions does not make sure the type is proper in runtime.

```js
// chrome.d.ts
declare interface HTMLMediaElement {
    setSinkId?: (sinkId: string) => Promise<void>
    // setSinkId is undefined on FireFox by default
}
```

In this way your definition of `HTMLMediaElement` now includes `setSinkId`.

Then use:

```
element.setSinkId?.(sinkId)
```